# Normal closure of closed subgroup is closed in a f.g. profinite group?

Tags: normal-subgroups, topological-groups, profinite-groups

Is there an example of a topologically finitely generated profinite group $G$ and a closed subgroup $H$ such that we simultaneously have:

1. The profinite normal closure $L$ of $H$ is open in $G$.
2. The abstract normal closure $\Lambda$ of $H$ is not closed in $G$.

We clearly have that $\Lambda$ is dense in $L$, so (1) + (2) is equivalent by the result of Nikolov and Segal to:

1. The profinite normal closure $L$ of $H$ is open in $G$.
2. The abstract normal closure $\Lambda$ of $H$ has infinite index in $G$.

It seems to me that this should be impossible by a standard inverse limit argument, but I still couldn't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: However, there may be a minimal counter example in the semidirect product $\mathbb{Z}_p \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_p$ with presentation $\langle x,y | yxy^{-1} = x^{1+p}\rangle$. If $\mu$ is an element of $p\mathbb{Z}_p$ that is not in the image of $\mathbb{Z}$, then for $H = \overline{\langle y \rangle}$ we have that $x^\mu$ should belong to $L$ but I see no clear way for it to belong $\Lambda$..

Comment: On the above example we actually might have $\Lambda = L$. Indeed, for $K = \overline{\langle x\rangle}$, the crossed product structure gives a continuous crossed homomorphism $D\colon H \to K$ given by $D(y^a) = y^axy^{-a}x^{-1}$. By continuity, the image of $H$ in $K$ is compact and thus closed, it must contain $x^{p^k}$ for all $k\geq 1$, as well as some combinations, so it might as well be the case that $D(H) = p\mathbb{Z}_p$.